# Code Help - Used scanner to initialize string array. When displaying, array values are all blank

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently taking a beginning Computer Science course and for one of our assignments we basically have to create a magic eight ball using an array where the user inputs the amount of values in the array and also inputs the values themselves in the array using a loop. After writing the code, I tested it and found that for some reason it wasn't setting the input into the array like it was supposed to it and after hours tweaking and trying to figure out what's wrong with it I still have no clue. Any help would be much appreciated.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer = "a";
    String question = " ";
    int currentResponse = 0;

    out.println("How many responses would you like there to be?");
    int numResponses = input.nextInt();

    String[] responses = new String[numResponses];

   //This is the loop that's the problem:

   for (int i = 0; i < numResponses; i++)
    {
      out.println("Enter an answer: "); 
      answer = input.nextLine(); 
      responses[i] = answer; //Should set the array value to the input 
      input.next();  //It kept skipping the input part the first time 
//so I added this
    } 

    //This is where I tried two different ways of printing out the array to 
//test it just in case that was the problem:

    out.println(Arrays.toString(responses));

    for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) 
    {
      System.out.print(responses[i] + " ");
    }

    while (!question.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
    {
      out.println("What is your question?");
      question = input.nextLine();
      input.next();

      currentResponse = (int)(Math.random()*numResponses);
      out.println(currentResponse);
      out.println(responses[currentResponse]); //It also doesn't appear to 
//actually print this out but I think that that's because the values are //blank 
spaces
    }

    out.println("Thank you for using the Magic Eight Ball");
```

The output should be something like

```
How many responses would you like there to be?
 4 //The input
Enter an answer: 
 s
Enter an answer: 
 d
Enter an answer: 
 f
Enter an answer: 
 g

[s,d,f,g]

    What is your question?
 s
0 //The randomized array index number
s //The value of that index

What is your question?
 d
2
f

What is your question?
 g
1
g
```

instead it's currently

```
 4
Enter an answer: 
 s
Enter an answer: 
 d
Enter an answer: 
 f
Enter an answer: 
 g

[, , , ]

    What is your question?
 s
0 //the randomized array index number

What is your question?
 d
2

What is your question?
 g
1
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I should’ve included it in the code here  but I’ve imported System.out so that I wouldn’t have to type out System.out all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.nextInt();` only consumes the integer entered, it doesn't consume the newline character entered after it.  To get around this you can use `input.nextLine();` to consume the newline char after it.  Then you should be able to remove the `input.next();` from the end of the for loop when taking in the responses.

You can also remove the `input.next();` within the question loop later on as that's not needed as well -- the `input.nextLine();` consumes the whole line.

Here's the adjusted code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer = "a";
    String question = " ";
    int currentResponse = 0;

    System.out.println("How many responses would you like there to be?");
    int numResponses = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    String[] responses = new String[numResponses];

    //This is the loop that's the problem:

    for (int i = 0; i < numResponses; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an answer: ");
        answer = input.nextLine();
        responses[i] = answer; //Should set the array value to the input
    }

    //This is where I tried two different ways of printing out the array to
    //test it just in case that was the problem:

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(responses));

    for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(responses[i] + " ");
    }

    while (!question.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is your question?");
        question = input.nextLine();
        currentResponse = (int)(Math.random() * numResponses);
        System.out.println(currentResponse);
        System.out.println(responses[currentResponse]); //It also doesn't appear to
    //actually print this out but I think that that's because the values are //blank spaces
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you for using the Magic Eight Ball");
}
```

Some additional documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed the issue.